# Pass Apollo graphql query as a store in Svelte?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, svelte, vite

Does anyone knows a way to pass the Apollo query as a *Svelte store*. I don't want put in a store the data that's returned by the `query(...)` function but the actual query. This is because I want to trigger `.refetch()`s from other components different that the one the one that is executing the query.

As of today, what I am doing to trigger refetches on other components, is passing down the query object as a prop to other components. I seem to be able to do that through prop-drilling, but when I try to do the same using Svelte stores, I will get all kinds of errors.

##### A: How I am doing it right now

(Disclaimer: the following is a simplification of the actual repo I'm trying to reproduce this in which you can see [here](https://github.com/BitterWorks/svelte-flow-test/tree/WF3-LS))

1. Let's say we have the following file-tree composed of a main component where I execute the graphql query with [svelte-apollo](https://github.com/timhall/svelte-apollo) in order to pass it down to both it's immediate children:  `<Form/>` and `<Fruits/>`.

```
src/
 |_ components
     |_Index.svelte --> Here I make the query to get the fruit list
        |_Fruits.svelte
        |  |_FruitCards.svelte 
        |     |_EditFruitCard.svelte --> Refetch after updating a fruit
        |     |_ViewFruitCard.svelte --> Refetch after deleting a fruit
        |_Form.svelte --> Refetch after creating a new fruit
```

1. The `<Form/>` creates a new Fruit in our backend using a mutation. We want to pass the query object to refetch the fruit list right after creating a new fruit.
   3.The `<Fruits/>` component will render the query inside an `{#await...}` block or `{#if}` block to show something while the data is loading. Once it's loaded, it will pass the loaded data to the `<FruitCards />` component to render the actual obtained data.
2. The `<FruitCards />`, depending if it's id is on a `let editing = []` or not, will either render the fruit object inside an "editing mode" card (`<EditFruitCard />`) or a "view mode" card (`<ViewFruitCard />`).
3. From `<EditFruitCard />` we will make an update mutation, so we will want to trigger a refetch after editing to see the updated list. And from `<ViewFruitCard />` we will be able to delete the object, so we will want to trigger a re-render as well.

##### B: What I wish to do

I wish to import the query object as a Svelte store. I want to execute it on my `<FruitCard />` compoenent and want to also import it inside `<Form/>`, `<EditFruitCard/>` and `<ViewFruitCard/>` and use it's `.refetch()` method to trigger a rerender:

```
src/
 |_ components
     |_Index.svelte --> Nothing here
        |_Fruits.svelte --> Import here
        |  |_FruitCards.svelte 
        |     |_EditFruitCard.svelte --> Import here
        |     |_ViewFruitCard.svelte --> Import here
        |_Form.svelte --> Import here
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried putting the `refetch` function obtained from the original query into a store on its own? Is this what generated errors, and if so, which?

Comment: 1) It's not a function but a object's method
2) You mean intializing an empty writable and later (let's say, inside the lifecycle method `onMount` on a component like `App.svelte`) setting it's value to `=  .refetch`? I'm afraid this would make an even less-clean solution when the original  aim of my question is to clean my already-working but not so clean solution.